# AssertRaises Doesn't Work with PsycoPg2

Tags: python, unit-testing, psycopg2, python-unittest

I am trying to test that an error is thrown in `unittest` with Python 3.6 when working with `psycopg2`. In this case, the database named `foo` does not existm, and it should throw an `OperationalError` because the database is not a valid one.

Here is a sample test case:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import unittest
import psycopg2
import logging


def pull_pg_data(conn, cursor, first, last):
    try:
        cursor.execute('SELECT first_name, last_name, email, street FROM user_data WHERE first_name =%s AND last_name=%s',(first, last))
    except psycopg2.OperationalError as msg:
        logging.error(msg)
        raise
    conn.commit()
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result


class SampleTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        try:
            self.conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='postgres', user='postgres', host='localhost', port=5432,
                                         connect_timeout=10)
        except psycopg2.OperationalError as msg:
            logging.critical(msg)
            raise
        self.conn.autocommit = True
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_data', [])
        self.cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE user_data (first_name TEXT, last_name TEXT, email TEXT, street TEXT)', [])
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO user_data(first_name, last_name, email, street) VALUES('someFirstName', 'someLastName', 'some@example.com', '123 road')",[])

    def test_pull_pg_data_fail(self):
        conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='foo', user='postgres', host='localhost', port=5432, connect_timeout=10)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        self.assertRaises(psycopg2.OperationalError, pull_pg_data, conn, cursor, 'someFirstName', 'someLastName')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run the test, it does indeed throw an error, but it fails the test. I don't know what I am doing incorrectly with `assertRaises`, because I do want to test that the error is thrown when I try to connect to a database that does not exist.

Comment: With mysql is the same issue.